# Properly reading and obtaining data from pandas dataframe with different header rows

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have this excel file that contains traffic volume for a certain intersection at different timestamps, which are further categorized by their traffic movement; see attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InSpd.png)

My objective is to move this data to another file based on their timestamps and their traffic movement. How I wanted to achieve this was to basically group the timestamps to different parts of the day (grouped by AM, PM, Night, etc.) and then group the traffic movement (into a tuple?) where I use the location (using `iloc` or `get_loc()`?) of the pair to retrieve my data. So, if I wanted the data for AM (7 - 8) going Westbound, Right, the output should be:

> 28 38 39 42 43

The first issue is getting the appropriate dataframe. If I run

```
df_start_time = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=worksheet_name, skiprows=10)
```

It will load the appropriate timestamps under "Start Time" but exclude the row above it, which reads part of the traffic movement (Westbound, Northbound, etc.)
If I run

```
df_compass = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=worksheet_name, skiprows=9)
```

then the code does not recognize where "Start Time" is because of the empty cell above it.

The related issue is properly slicing the data based on the traffic movement. Because they are in two different rows (ex. "Westbound" in row 10, "Right" in row 11), I'm not sure how to read both of them into the pandas dataframe and properly satisfy both conditions to retrieve the appropriate data in those specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could define multi-index columns, use the Start Time as the index and then access the data directly.

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=worksheet_name, skiprows = 8 , header = [0, 1, 2])

df = df.set_index(df.columns[0], drop = True)
df.index.names = ['Start Time']

print(df)
```

which gives for the DataFrame:

```
           47th Street 12th Avenue           
             Westbound  Northbound Southbound
                 Right        Thru       Thru
Start Time                                   
07:00:00            28         498        821
07:15:00            38         577        905
07:30:00            39         604        890
07:45:00            42         627        666
08:00:00            43         648        813
08:15:00            41         626        828
```

and then (for example):

```
print(df['47th Street','Westbound','Right'])
```

gives:

```
Start Time
07:00:00    28
07:15:00    38
07:30:00    39
07:45:00    42
08:00:00    43
08:15:00    41
Name: (47th Street, Westbound, Right), dtype: int64
```

and you can then access and manipulate the DF as required. To use .loc then specify the index and the column multi-index. Note that `Start Time` is in **datetime.time** format as that has been assumed in `read_excel`

```
t = pd.to_datetime('07:15:00', format = '%H:%M:%S').time()
print(df.loc[t, ('47th Street',  'Westbound',   'Right')])
```

gives:

```
38
```

Comment: Your code did work as intended and is showing the dataframe in its proper format, thank you for that. However, when trying to index a sample of the data as you mentioned, it returned a KeyError: '47th Street', 'Westbound', 'Right'. I tried adding another pair of brackets to the index line of code and it returned KeyError: "['47th Street' 'Westbound' 'Right'] not in index. Am I missing something to properly index my data?

Comment: I am not sure what you have tried to do so can't comment specifically. My answer was trying to establish the principle of using a multi-index. I have now edited the answer to add another example which may get you further along the road. Using such indexing, which flows from your Excel formatting, takes a while to get familiar with but is well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went down a bit of a rabbit hole and found that I need to sort my index as it impacts performance. I used `df2 = df.sort_index()` first, then `df2.loc[:,('Westbound', 'Right')]` to select columns from a multindex. It does work, but for some reason, it does not start from the beginning Start Time (7:00) and randomly jumps to times before and after. Will have to research a bit more. Thank you for also showing how I can possibly specify index based on the Start Time. That was also part of my next step in this process.