# How do I prevent reordering of datetime/ strings and preserve the order as input?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this list of strings from an excel sheet (sample):

> 7:00 7:15 7:30 7:45 8:00 8:15 8:30 8:45 9:00 9:15 9:30 9:45 10:00
> 11:00 11:15 11:30 11:45 12:00 12:15 12:30 12:45

I am using these timestamps as my index for a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0], drop = True)
        
df.index.names = ['Start Time']

# Convert 'Start Time' to datetime format
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%H:%M").strftime("%H:%M")

df_tcc = df.sort_index()
```

I'm required to convert them into datetime objects so I can compare them with other timestamps to select a range of data from the dataset. When I use this code however, the order of the timestamps are rearranged:

```
Index(['07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '07:45', '08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45',
       '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '11:00', '11:15', '11:30',
       '11:45', '12:00', '12:00', '12:15', '12:15', '12:30', '12:30', '12:45',
       '12:45', '13:00', '13:00', '13:15', '13:15', '13:30', '13:30', '13:45',
       '13:45', '14:00', '14:00', '14:15', '14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15',
       '15:30', '15:45', '16:00', '16:00', '16:15', '16:15', '16:30', '16:30',
       '16:45', '16:45', '17:00', '17:00', '17:15', '17:15', '17:30', '17:30',
       '17:45', '17:45', '18:00', '18:00', '18:15', '18:15', '18:30', '18:30',
       '18:45', '18:45', '19:00', '19:00', '19:15', '19:15', '19:30', '19:30',
       '19:45', '19:45', '20:00', '20:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Start Time')
```

How do I prevent this and ensure the order is the same as the input?

Comment: Why are you sorting them if you don't want to sort them? Maybe I'm missing something. Could you provide a [mre]? You have values in the output that aren't present in the input. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant to the problem, but: datetimes and strings aren't always interchangeable, and `strftime` converts datetimes to strings.

Comment: Do you have duplicates times in your "Start Time" column?  How did you expect to handle those?

Comment: I added .sort_index() because apparently it impacts performance if I don't. See related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77829352/properly-reading-and-obtaining-data-from-pandas-dataframe-with-different-header
And I provided only a sample of the input as it is a long list. Yes, there are duplicates of the timestamps, which is why I don't want them re ordered and I'm trying to select a specific timestamp from the duplicates

Comment: If I don't add in strftime, then the timestamps will have the date associated with them, which I do not want.

Comment: I guess you'll have to take the performance hit then?... I'm not sure what to tell you without more details. I looked at the linked question, but it also doesn't have an MRE so I'm not sure. Maybe you have another column containing the date? That's the most likely reason I can think of why you have times that aren't in order.

Comment: Regarding "it is a long list" -- then make a short list that has the same problem. See the links in my first comment.

Comment: I recommend not using time as the index, but as a regular column. You can do everything with column values that you can do with the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last line from your code if you dont want to sort it (a.k.a. changing the order).

`df = df.set_index(df.columns[0], drop = True)`

`df.index.names = ['Start Time']`

`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%H:%M").strftime("%H:%M")`

<s>`df_tcc = df.sort_index()`</s>